# Editing a layout to use a vertical rule between elements.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following reduced test case:

http://jsfiddle.net/QL49W/

In my design image, this is what I'm going for:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNDav.jpg

In the footer, you can see that I'm adding a horizontal rule between the e-mail deals & catalogs sections. However, I'm not sure how to accomplish that via code.

My HTML is below. In the JSFiddle, I'm using a ton of external CSS, and JS.

```
<section id="newslettersignup">
    <div class="container White_BG">
        <div class="pull-left newsletter">
            <h2>E-mail Deals</h2>
            Sign up to receive Sales &amp; exclusive news!<br>
            We will not sell or rent your email address. <a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/privacy-policy/a/3/" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#F25C27;">Privacy Policy</a>.<br><br>
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="http://www.gliq.com/cgi-bin/subunsub">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="hidden" name="acctname" value="amleo">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
                    <input type="hidden" name="url" value=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/subscribe-successful/a/47/">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputIcon" class="input-xlarge" name="email">
                    <input value="SUBSCRIBE" class="btn btn-orange" type="submit">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="Catalog" class="pull-right catrr">
            <div class="catalog">
                    <h2>Catalogs</h2>
                    <a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/catalogs.aspx" title="Catalogs" style="text-decoration:underline;"><font color="#F25C27">View our online catalog</font></a>, or <br><br><a class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="catalogrequestpopup.aspx?catalog_id=0001&amp;name=2014 Catalog Request" title="Request a Catalog" style="text-decoration:underline;">
                    <font color="#F25C27">request a free catalog now!</font></a><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ---------- CSS -----------
// remove or update container width. Its now width: 730px should be .

.container {
    /* width:724px; */
}

#newslettersignup .newsletter {
    min-width: 414px;
    border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
}


-------------HTML --------------
//Remove class catrr from div
<div class="pull-right catrr" id="Catalog">
.......           
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, but one super easy solution is just adding a wrapper div to your 'catalogs' section and adding a border to the left only, with sufficient padding to put it where you want it.

Also sticking a 1px wide block element between the two and giving that a border is easy and tweakable. Both of these are nice because they will move and scale with the element without you needing to add some horrible absolute positioning logic.